# How can I sort a list of strings by numbers in them?

Tags: perl, sorting, numbers, natural-sort

I have a list of filenames which are like so:

```
fw_d.log.1.gz  
through  
fw_d.log.300.gz
```

When I use this code block below, it almost sorts it the way I want, but not quite:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
my $basedir = "/var/log";
my @verdir = qw(fw_d);
my $fulldir;
my $configs;
my $combidir;

foreach $combidir (@verdir) {
    $fulldir = "$basedir/$combidir";
    opendir (DIR, $fulldir);
    my @files = grep { $_ ne '.' && $_ ne '..' && $_ ne 'CVS' readdir DIR;
    closedir (DIR);
    @files1 = sort {$a cmp $b}(@files);
    foreach my $configs (@files1) {
        print "Checking $configs\n";
        system("less $basedir/$combidir/$configs | grep \'.* Group = , Username = .* autheauthenticated.\' >> output.log" );
    }
}
```

Here is a snippet output:

```
Checking fw_d.log  
Checking fw_d.log.1.gz  
Checking fw_d.log.10.gz  
Checking fw_d.log.100.gz  
Checking fw_d.log.101.gz  
Checking fw_d.log.102.gz
```

As you can see, it almost sorts it how I was hoping... Does anyone have any suggestions, on either reading, or a code snippet I can use?

Comment: What is the problem? I see that the files are in order. How would you want them sorted?

Comment: @qtax, they are indeed in order, but not numerical order, as i have files from 1-300 they should go 1,2.3 not  1 100 101

Comment: oh, thought you just omitted those lines for some reason. You should use `<=>` to sort on the number values, like M42's answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could use [Schartzian-transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) :

```
my @sorted = map  { $_->[0] }
             sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }
             map  { [$_, $_=~/(\d+)/] }
                 @files;
print Dumper \@sorted;
```

Added benchmark for comparison between Schwartzian-Transform and subroutine

```
use Benchmark qw(:all);

# build list of files
my @files = map {'fw_d.log.'.int(rand()*1000).'.log' } 0 ..300;

my $count = -3;
my $r = cmpthese($count, {
        'subname' => sub {
              sub expand {
                   my $file=shift; 
                   $file=~s{(\d+)}{sprintf "%04d", $1}eg;
                   return $file;
              }
              my @sorted = sort { expand($a) cmp expand($b) } @files;
        },
        'schwartzian' => sub {
              my @sorted = map  { $_->[0] }
                           sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }
                           map  { [$_, $_=~/(\d+)/] }
                 @files;
         }
});
```

**Result:**

```
              Rate     subname schwartzian
subname     21.2/s          --        -92%
schwartzian  279/s       1215%          --
```

Schwartzian-transform is about 13 times more efficient for sorting 300 files.

Comment: While we're nitpicking... I don't think the bench is actually representative of the data: the real order would be the alphabetical order initially mentioned by the OP, generated with my @files = sort map {"fw_d.log.$_.log" } 0 ..300;

Comment: running the benchmark with the proper data, the Schwartzian transform "only" speed it up 8x

Answer (score 12):

the problem is that the code does what you tell it to do: sort the file names in alphabetical order.

You should replace `sort { $a cmp $b }` by `sort { expand($a) cmp expand($b) }`

with `expand`:

```
sub expand 
   { my $file=shift; 
     $file=~s{(\d+)}{sprintf "%04d", $1}eg; # expand all numbers to 4 digits
     return $file;
   }
```

Comment: While the "g" increases the flexibility, I don't believe that the "e" (expression evaluation) is necessary.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner the e allows the sprintf to be evaluated, without it the code doesn't work (I should know, I forgot it the first time I tried it!)

Comment: NB: That only works on integers; when you have decimal numbers like 1.1 and 1.02 and 1.201 and such, it gets things wrong. Signed numbers will also be a problem. I do have code that does the right thing for these, but it’s too big to fit into the comment. :) You can find [a rather elaborate prototype here](http://training.perl.com/scripts/FixStrings.pm), although it does several other things, too, like normalization Roman numerals and Greek letternames written in Latin script.

Comment: @tchrist agreed with the possible limitations, although I have always found cases where the method I use works (ie 1.2 would sort before 1.10 because it has never been the number 1.2 but rather 1 and 2, that happened to be separated by a dot). Also your link doesn't work.

Comment: @mirod: Apologies on link. I just made a symlink to the real link. I forgot that it had no s at the end.  Link works now. Always try [enclosing directory](http://training.perl.com/scripts/) if things befoul.

Answer (score 7):

What you can try is using a custom sort function:

```
sub sort_by_number {
    $a =~ /(\d+)/;
    $numa = $1;
    $b =~ /(\d+)/;
    $numb = $1;

    return $numa <=> $numb;
}
```

and then sort like this:

```
@files1 = sort sort_by_number @files;
```

This will sort the strings in `@files` by the value of the first number in each string.

Comment: The pattern "/ ( \ d + \ )" should be changed to "/(\d+)"

Comment: they should make vim a comment/post editor here on SO. ;) flash vim?

Comment: This was really helpful - just seeing the "return" statement explained what I was missing about custom sort functions.

Answer (score 2):

Older question, but there's an answer as yet unmentioned.

[`Sort::Naturally`](http://search.cpan.org/~bingos/Sort-Naturally-1.03/lib/Sort/Naturally.pm) does this for you:

> Sort lexically, but sort numeral parts numerically

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Sort::Naturally;

print nsort <DATA>;

__DATA__
fw_d.log  
fw_d.log.101.gz  
fw_d.log.1.gz  
fw_d.log.10.gz  
fw_d.log.100.gz 
fw_d.log.2.gz  
fw_d.log.102.gz  
fw_d.log.12.gz
```

This orders as:

```
fw_d.log  
fw_d.log.1.gz  
fw_d.log.2.gz  
fw_d.log.10.gz  
fw_d.log.12.gz
fw_d.log.100.gz 
fw_d.log.101.gz  
fw_d.log.102.gz
```