# character should appear few times before search string

Tags: regex, perl

Say I have this part of data:

```
asdsad;adafds;asfdafas;frewf;gggf
121132;sadf12;124fd;1243fd;dfgfew
```

... the string delimiter is `;`

How can I get the 4rd part of each line? ie. `; ; ;[this];`

This doesn't work: `;{3}(\w+)`

I need regex expression because I want to use it in the Schartzian-transform

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my $fourth = (split ';', $_)[3];
    print "$fourth\n";
}

__DATA__
asdsad;adafds;asfdafas;frewf;gggf
121132;sadf12;124fd;1243fd;dfgfew
```

Outputs:

```
frewf
1243fd
```

Comment: Yeah that would work but I need regex as I want to use this in a map statement. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282574/how-can-i-sort-a-list-of-strings-by-numbers-in-them

Comment: Nothing stops you from using a `split` inside a `map`.  `my @fourths = map {(split ';', $_)[3]} @array;`  Even in a schwartian transform

Comment: It does work and I think it's faster than regex, thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following regex:

`([^;]+;){3}([^;]+)`

and the second captured group (`\2` or `$2`) will contain what you want:

For example: (`\2`/`$2`) above would contain `frewf` and `1243fd` in your question above

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/uN5fD9